# Swift 1.2 - Setting element in array of optional types to nil-- not allowed when passed in?

Tags: ios, swift, null, sprite-kit

I've an array of boxes where the types are Box? to allow elements to be set to nil, if there is nothing there. I want the Box to set its spot to nil when it is removed from the scene.

**The following causes no complaints from Xcode:**

```
override func removeFromParent() {
        var board = [[Box?]](count: 5, repeatedValue: [Box?](count: 9, repeatedValue: nil))
        board[i][j] = nil
        super.removeFromParent()
    }
```

and neither does making the board variable global and using it that way...

**In GameScene.swift:**

```
var board = [[Box?]](count: 5, repeatedValue: [Box?](count: 9, repeatedValue: nil))
```

**in Box.swift:**

```
override func removeFromParent() {
        board[i][j] = nil
        super.removeFromParent()
    }
```

But trying to do this wont compile (It's no longer overriding because I added a parameter):

```
func removeFromParent(board: [[Box?]]) {
        board[i][j] = nil
        super.removeFromParent()
    }
```

Is there any way to make this work? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `board` in the latter case is a `let` and can not be changed.

Again the Swift error message is misleading here.

If you want it to be an `inout` parameter then add this like `(inout board:...` but then you need to pass the parameter by reference with an `&` in the call like `removeFromParent(&myBoxArray)`.

**PS** Just tried this in Playground:

```
var a:[Int] = [1, 2, 3]
func aa(inout a:[Int]) {
  a[1] = 9
}

aa(&a)
a // return [1, 9, 3]
```

Comment: How do I pass it as a `var`?